# what are contraction(Lipschitz) maps on $\mathbb C$?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis, complex-numbers

We say  a map $f:\mathbb C \to \mathbb C$ is contraction(Lipschitz) if $|f(z_{1})- f(z_{2})| \leq C |z_{1}- z_{2}|$ for every $z_{1}, z_{2} \in \mathbb C$ and $C$ is some constant.

Trivial Examples: (a) $f(z)= z, (z\in \mathbb C )$ (b) $f(z)= |z|, (z\in \mathbb C).$

> **My Question is**: (1) What other examples of contraction maps on $\mathbb C$ one can think of ? (2) Can we characterize contraction maps on $\mathbb C$ ?

Thanks,

Comment: A contraction is a Lipschitz mapping with Lipschitz constant  < 1!

Comment: Use the mean value theorem and consider functions with bounded derivatives on $\mathbb C$.

Comment: Is mean value theorem true for complex valued function ? I guess, its not applicable here!

Comment: I thought this, but my feeling is that we would view $\mathbb C$ as a Banach space. A quick search on Google shows a some ideas along these lines. I will try and show you how to generate a large class of examples later..

Comment: @dcs24; thanks;

Comment: The mean value theorem fails in $\mathbb C$ but the mean value inequality $|f(x)-f(y)|\le |f'(\xi)| |x-y|$ is true. However, if $f$ is everywhere differentiable then so is $f'$ and if the derivative is bounded then it is constant by Liouville's theorem.

Comment: @Jochen; thanks; but I have bit confusion, see $|f(x)-f(y)|\leq |f'(\xi)| |x-y|, x, y \in \mathbb C;$ where $\xi$ lies ? can you suggest some reference for this inequality ?

Comment: $\xi$ is somewhere on the segment joining $x$ and $y$. For the proof, take $z=f(x)-f(y)$ and apply the mean value theorem to $\varphi:[0,1]\to \mathbb R$, $t\mapsto \Re (\bar z f(x+t(y-x))$.

Answer (score 1):

If $f\colon\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C}$ is Lipschitz with constant $C$, then for all $z\in\mathbb{C}$
$$
|f(z)|=|f(z)-f(0)+f(0)|\le C\,|z|+|f(0)|.
$$
If $f$ is also (complex) differentiable (that is, it is an entire function), it follows from Liouville's theorem that $f(z)=A\,z+B$ for some $A,B\in\mathbb{C}$.

If no (complex) differentiability condition is required, there are many others. For instance $f(z)=|z|$ or $f(z)=u(x,y)+v(x,y)\,i$ where $u$ and $v$ have bounded partial derivatives.

Comment: @JA; thanks; sorry I could not follow; would you please tell me , why, $f(z)= u(x,y)+iv(x,y);$ ($u, v$ have bounded partial derivatives) is a contraction map ?

Comment: $|u(x,y)-u(x_0,y_0)|\le|u(x,y)-u(x_0,y)|+|u(x_0,y)-u(x_0,y_0)|$. Now use the mean value theorem. Same for $v$.